# How to get the round number if use the given rule

Tags: objective-c

I have a requirement:

I want there is a function, like this, if the number is:`323.01` I want return `500`.

If the number is `678.60`, I want to get the `1000`.

If the number is `20.0`, I want get `50`.

If the number is `8`, I want get `10`.

like this: if the first number of the number, if less than `5`, I want get `5`, if more than `5`, I want `10`.

How to realize this function in Objective-C?

---

I just think about the this, I only know use `%` to get the last number of given number, I don't know how to get the first number of the given number.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Stack overflow is not a place for getting your homework assignments solved for you.

Comment: @SU3 No, I just can not think out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would get number of digits (e.g. for 456 it is 3):

```
var originalNumber = 456
var counter = 0
var number = originalNumber
while(number != 0){
    counter = counter + 1
    number = number / 10
}
```

From there, you can test it for 5 or 10 with exponent of counter.

```
if (originalNumber < pow(10, counter - 1) * 5){
    number = pow(10, counter - 1) * 5
}
else {
    number = pow(10, counter)
}
```

I reused number variable, you can either return it or assign to other variable.

EDIT: just noticed that flag is Objective - C, same applies

```
Double originalNumber = 456;
int counter = 0;
int number = (int) originalNumber;
while(number != 0) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    number = number / 10;
}

if(originalNumber < pow(10,counter - 1) * 5){
    number = pow(10, counter -1) * 5;
}
else {
    number = pow(10, counter)
}
```